# Divide Number Array into chunk of 3 using Reduce

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There can be multiple approach to solve this but I am not sure why this one specifically is not working as expected.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].reduce((a, d, i, c) => [...a, c.splice(0, 3)], [])
```

Result - [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

Expected Result - [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8]]

Please do not change the approach as I want to know why this one is not working as expected.

Comment: I think because in 3rd iteration index is 2 and you are left with [7, 8] so its over.

Comment: @NenadVracar : `[7,8].splice(0,3)` returns `[7,8]`

Comment: But it breaks the loop because there is no element with index of 2 anymore only 0 and 1 because there are 2 elements left by that point.

Comment: @NenadVracar EXACTLY!!!!! Thank You so much. This solves my confusion

Comment: As usual you could use decrementing loop in these scenarios or in this case `reduceRight` [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].reduceRight((a, d, i, c) => [...a, c.splice(0, 3)], [])

Comment: @NenadVracar Thanks again for reduceRight

Comment: @NenadVracar : the last one (`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].reduceRight((a, d, i, c) => [...a, c.splice(0, 3)], [])`) is brilliant, it is certainly worth an answer.

Comment: @NenadVracar ^ same

Comment: @NenadVracar - I third the motion that `reduceRight` would make a great answer, perhaps to [the canonical "chunks" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks) (I don't see one there).

Comment: @NenadVracar Can you pls write an answer for this with reasoning. This was a good learning for me. Hope it will help others.

Comment: @Nitish Narang There is already a great answer from T.J. Crowder down there that explains this better then I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know why this one is not working as expected.

The problem is that you're removing entries from the original array, so `reduce` runs out of elements early because prior to each callback, it checks to see if the index it's about to visit is still less than the array length. After the second callback, the original array's length is `2`, and the index is `2`, so `reduce` stops, never producing the third chunk.

If you write it in its longer form, it's easier to see what's going on when you step through it in the debugger. Rather than recording a video, I'll just instrument the code:

```js
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].reduce((a, d, i, c) => {
  console.log("i", i, "c", JSON.stringify(c));
  return [...a, c.splice(0, 3)];
}, []);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
 }
```

As you can see, in the first calback all is good:

```
i 0 c [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

it's also okay in the second callback, but notice how `c` is shorter now:

```
i 1 c [4,5,6,7,8]
```

After `splice` has done its work in that second callback, though, `c` will be `[7, 8]` and so its length is just 2. `reduce` stops there, because `i` is now `2`, and it only continues when `i < length` is true. `2 < 2` is false, so it stops.

You can't do this reasonably with `reduce`. Instead, see the [canonical "chunk" array question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks). You *can* do it with `reduceRight` as [Nenad Vracar points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393335/divide-number-array-into-chunk-of-3-using-reduce/56393463#comment99385633_56393335). (Hopefully, he/she posts that as an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're mutating the array while iterating. In particular, the problem is that when `reduce` reaches the third element, there are only two elements.

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].reduce((a, d, i, c) => {
  console.log("current result", a)
  console.log("current element", d)
  console.log("index", i)
  console.log("array", c)
  return [...a, c.splice(0, 3)]
}, [])
```

So, when you get to the third iteration where `i` should be `2`, the content of the array (`c`) is `[7, 8]`. Since that cannot work, there is no third iteration.